# Convert a number to a string: write-to-string vs prin1-to-string vs princ-to-string

Tags: common-lisp

Suppose I have a number in Common Lisp, and I want to convert it to a string. There are at least three functions that can convert a number to a string: `write-to-string`, `prin1-to-string`, and `princ-to-string`.

As far as I am aware, all three functions give the same result when used on numbers. Is it really the case? Are there any edge cases I should be aware of? Which should I use?

Answer (score 4):

There should be no difference, but WRITE-TO-STRING has keyword arguments. For similar effects with the other two functions one would need to bind a printer variable around the call.

```
CL-USER 1 > (write-to-string 12 :base 16)
"C"

CL-USER 2 > (let ((*print-base* 16))
              (prin1-to-string 12))
"C"
```

FORMAT can also create strings:

```
CL-USER 3 > (format nil "~16R" 12)
"C"

CL-USER 4 > (format nil "~vR" 16 12)
"C"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth pointing out that you need to be *extremely* cautious about the slavering monsters which lurk around the corners when using any or all of `write-to-string`, `prin1-to-string`, and `princ-to-string`.

As an example consider this:

```
> (dotimes (i 20)
    (print i))

0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
six 
seven 
eight 
IX 
X 
XI 
XII 
XIII 
XII 
XIII 
XIII 
XIII 
XII 
XII 
nil
```

This is *entirely legal output* and any conforming implementation would produce it (or in fact something similar as there were some random numbers involved).

The way you get this is by having `*print-pretty*` set to true and then doing a couple of entertaining things to the pprint dispatch table.

This may be the greatest monster which lurks, but there are other, lesser ones: `*print-base*` `*print-radix*` among them.

At the *very least* you should surround calls to these functions with `(with-standard-io-syntax ...)` if you want to be sure that the output you get is the output you expect.

Using `format` (as in `(format nil "~D" n)`) is safer (you no longer need to care about things like `*print-base*` and `*print-radix*`) but it is still vulnerable to the ambient value of `*print-pretty*` and hence to the above games with the pprint dispatch table.  I believe (but am not entirely sure) that

```
(let ((*print-pretty* nil))
  (format nil "~D" 13))
```

should return the string `"13"`

Comment: How exactly did you get that output for `(dotimes (i 20) (print i))`?

Comment: @Flux: I don't remember in detail now, but (ab)use of the pretty printer interface.  CL's pretty printer is ... quite flexible.